# Bootstrap footer is overlapping the content on small screens?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with my bootstrap layout.

Basically, everything looks OK on larger screens but on smaller screens my footer overlaps the content or the content overlaps the footer!

This is the code I have: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/639029/

If you make the HTML part larger and smaller and look at the footer, you will see the issue.

This is my full code:

```css
html,body,.col-md-12,.row {
  height:100%;
}
.row > div {
  height:100%;
}
  
  .YOsidemenu{
 padding:0;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color: #ffc90e;
 padding-top:10px;
 max-width:200px;
 
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
.YOsidemenu{
 display:none;
}
}

  
/* to make columns visible */
.row .col-sm-2 {
  background-color:red;
}
.row .col-sm-10 {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div style="height:100%; background:#fff;width:100%;padding:0;" class="container">






<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            Sidebar content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            Body content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
    </div>
    
    
         <!-- Footer -->
 <section id="footer" style="text-align:left; !important">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left" style="text-align:left; !important">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <h5>Quick links</h5>
     
     
    <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="signin.php">Sign-in</a></li>
      <li><a href="affiliat-signup.php">affiliate</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Promote</a></li>
      
     </ul>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <h5>Support</h5>
     <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
      <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>support@email.com</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>+44 7842227819</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>www.website.com</a></li>
 
     </ul>
    </div>

   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
     <p>this site a registered company. </p>
     <p class="h6">&copy All right Reversed.<a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank">website</a></p>
    </div>
    </hr>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </section>
 <!-- ./Footer -->
```

Could someone please be kind enough and help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `height: 100%` from the div. On mobile the container is `100%` high, but because the columns get stacked and each column inherits the height, you have a parent with 100% height and two columns with each 100%, making it 200% of height.

Comment: I've got a few 100% height. which one are you referring to?

Comment: if you are refrring to this: `<div style=" height:100%;background:#fff;width:100%;padding:0;" class="container">` then I cannot remove the height from that because it will break the 100% height for the red/green div's.

Comment: @williamwolly yes. you can try to add it via a class instead of inline css. give the columns a height of 100vh (100vh = 100% screen height). on mobile you can then adjust the height as you like or reset the height completely

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
html,
body,
.col-md-12,
.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.row>div {
  height: 100%;
}

.YOsidemenu {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffc90e;
  padding-top: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .YOsidemenu {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* to make columns visible */

.row .col-sm-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.row .col-sm-10 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div style="height:100%; background:#fff;width:100%;padding:0;" class="container">






  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        Sidebar content
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        Body content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!-- Footer -->
<section id="footer" style="text-align:left; !important">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left" style="text-align:left; !important">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <h5>Quick links</h5>


        <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="signin.php">Sign-in</a></li>
          <li><a href="affiliat-signup.php">affiliate</a></li>
          <li><a href="signup.php">Promote</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <h5>Support</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled quick-links">
          <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>support@email.com</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>+44 7842227819</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>www.website.com</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
        <p>this site a registered company. </p>
        <p class="h6">&copy All right Reversed.<a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank">website</a></p>
      </div>
      </hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- ./Footer -->
```

Comment: @williamwolly which one are you mentioning. Can you comment the overlapping content that you see?

Comment: appologies. sent you the wrong fiddle link.. Please view issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/639111/